# Localizing dynamic, user generated content. Opinions on these two choices?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, localization, user-generated-content

I'm building a website that will allow people to create content and place comments on content.

For things like form label, buttons, and other static content, I can use a `.resx` file. I've done it before and it works out OK.

Now I'm at a crossroad where I don't know which path to take. Both sound equally good to me, but since this is going to be my first foray into such territory, I'd rather ask about any pitfalls I may not be taking into consideration.

Here are two options I thought of implementing. Both would solve my problem of localizing and presenting user generated content to my users.

**Option A:**

---

I would create multiple copies of the entire MVC3 application and place each localization into it's own IIS Application.

```
foobar.com
es.foobar.com
ru.foobar.com
```

And I would just need to change a web.config file, to use a different database for each localization.

I see some problems with this, for example:

- If a user logs into `foobar.com` and he were to visit his localized version of the site, he would not be logged in, since they are two completely separate applications.
- No unified moderation tools. I would have to go inside each application, log in, access the admin panel and moderate from there.
- Difficult to push changes/updates to all versions of the page. I'd have to manually go into each IIS application folder and copy the published files for each localized version.

**Option B:**

---

I would create a single MVC3 application and on the backend database create multiple fields for each localization.

For example:

```
Car
------
CarID
Name
esName
ruName
Make
esMake
ruMake
..and so on..
```

I would then somehow dynamically choose what fields to display based on what localization is chosen. Although I'm not even sure this is possible since visiting a subdomain would take me to a completely different IIS application, unless I can bind a subdomain to point to the actual domain on my IIS.

```
foobar.com
es.foobar.com
ru.foobar.com
```

The problem I see with this approach is that each table would be gargantuan in size, not only in number of fields, but also in number of records. I'm not sure if this would be a problem.

---

I would appreciate some suggestions on how to implement localization for user generated content in an MVC3 application.

Meaning, a user visiting the Spanish version (`es.foobar.com`) would see other spanish content and comments made by users, and *not* other versions. I **do not** mean translating their content and presenting it to the end user.

Comment: Why not just do yoursite.com/en/customer/1 and let the route parameter of en allow you to set the culture and pull from resource file or database, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to have a single MVC application, localized in the normal way, and with a language switch (which you can trigger through URL routing, such as es.foobar.com would set the language to "es", or through the `accept-languages` header, or through a UI selector).

Instead of having one column per language, you could add a language ID column to the table(s) that hold your user-generated content. And implement a filter on your user-generated content so that you present only the rows which match the active language.

For example:

```
Car
----------
CarID
LanguageID
Name
Make
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to store a pointer to a field in your data tables. For example your Car table could contain

```
CarId | Name | Make
123   | 0099 | 0100
```

Then have a table that contains the localized strings.

```
TextId | Lang | String
0099   | en   | "Escape"
0099   | ru   | "Russian Name"
0100   | en   | "Ford"
0100   | ru   | "Russian Ford"
```

On the localized string table, create a composite primary key on TextId and Lang. That way your domain/data tables remain simple, and when selecting data you can just join the localized string table. Make sense? I could write a quick SQL Query to give you the idea if you need it.

This approach does require additional work on the database, but the hit isn't too bad. I've used this approach on a moderately loaded website. If it does turn into a problem, you can create materialized views for the different languages. I've done this as well, and as long as most of your queries are reads, it is very fast.

Erick

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could do this:

- Make just one MVC3 site (one IIS site)
- Use the .rsx for static content changing the language as usual
- Localization database: one per language.
- If you need a database for other things that are not localization, that should be a separated database (not one per language)
- Once the user enters a localized site, you use the corresponding connection string

**CONS:**

- You will need to trigger database updates in all databases